# Responsive image coordinates

Tags: jquery, image, tagging

I have created an image marking system using jQuery. For each click on the image, I am taking the coordinates of that point and storing them in a database. However, after making this system responsive, my tag position changes. How do I keep the coordinates of the image, not the screen.

This is my code:

```
$(document).on('click','.imageContainer',function(e){
    //alert($(this).width());

var pOffset=$(this).parent().offset();

var pwidth= $(this).width();
    var pagex=  e.pageX;
    var screenx= e.screenX;
    var offset =e.offsetX;

    left = (pagex-pOffset.left)+10;
     top = (e.pageY-pOffset.top)+10;
   });
```